# How to use a npm library created for react-native without publishing to npm

Tags: react-native, npm

I created a npm libary using
[react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library). I can publish the newly created library into npm. But as I developing, I'm not able to test it locally with a react-native project.

If I tried to add by adding the file path to dependancy section of package.json
then I'm getting this error

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-test-library-abcd-one` from `C:\Users\kk\TestLibABCD1\LibraryTester\App.js`: Module `react-native-test-library-abcd-one` does not exist in the Haste module map

It will work if I do a 
npm install react-native-test-library-abcd-one.

How can I link my local libaray in this case?

Comment: You can use `npm pack` to pack the package and install it using `npm install [absolute path]`. Checkout this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@the1mills/how-to-test-your-npm-module-without-publishing-it-every-5-minutes-1c4cb4b369be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the git clone url set against the library name in your `package.json`.

**Thats how incrementally the bigger softwares/libraries are developed** You should versionize it using git or something else. :)

That should look like:

```
"react-native-touch-id": "https://github.com/surajj2223/react-native-touch-id.git"
```

If that would not have been your library then a simple use case where such thing is needed:  You alter some code as per your need  in some specific library so you have your own version of the library now and upon next `npm install/yarn install` you lose your changes if you have not uploaded that on git.
So what can be done is,

1. Fork the original library.
2. Clone it and make changes to it and push it.
3. Now use your library's clone url against the library name in your `package.json`
4. `npm install/yarn install` and you are good to go now.

And if you make some really generic changes that others would also be needing then its always better to make a pull request to the original library and get it merged thereby helping the community too.